# Appending a codepoint to a java.lang.Appendable

Tags: java, standard-library

[`java.lang.Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) supports `append(char)` but not `appendCodepoint(int)`.

Is there any efficient way (no object creation) using the standard libraries to append a codepoint to an `Appendable` that works with supplemental codepoints?

I'd rather not roll my own UTF-16 encode function, and everything in `java.lang.Character` requires mucking around with `char[]`s.

Comment: Wouldn't [`Character.highSurrogate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#highSurrogate(int)) and [`Character.lowSurrogate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#lowSurrogate(int)) do? (And their friends that tell you whether that's needed.)

Comment: @millimoose, Yep.  Those'll help if I do have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

I mean, it sounds like what you want is just to do `Character.toChars(int)` without the array overhead, right?  Here's the source of [`Character.toChars`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.toChars%28int%29); it's not particularly complicated to replicate yourself.

Comment: You are correct about the array overhead; I plan to use this in an inner loop.  I would rather not reinvent this wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: I mean, your other alternative is the [`Character.toChars(int, char[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars(int,%20char[],%20int)) overload, which lets you just allocate a single `char[2]` and reuse it continuously over the course of your inner loop.  That's really the only other alternative I think you'll find.